# SharePoint DataView: How to combine data from multiple source columns into a single display column

Tags: sharepoint, dataview

I have a DataView web part which displays user information including address. The address is in multiple columns in the list (Address1, Address2, Street, City, Zip). I want to combine these fields and display them in a single column so that full address is displayed.

I am new to DataView web part and have not found a solution so far. Is this possible and does the solution requires editing the DataView XSL? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know the data view web part, you have to edit die Data View XSL, but this is very simple.

Open the page in the MS SharePoint Designer for edit, at the buttom bar, click on "Split", so that you see also the code behind the page. You also have to click on "Advanced Mode" in the Home-Ribbon bar.

In the Code-Page, you have to search for your web-part code, in the xsl-templates, you will find someting like:

```
<tr>
<td class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of select="@Address1" /></td>
<td class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of select="@Address2" /></td>
<td class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of select="@Street" /></td>
<td class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of select="@City" /></td>
<td class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of select="@Zip" /></td></tr>
```

Now you have to change this code to:

```
<tr>
<td class="ms-vb"><xsl:value-of select="@Address1" /><BR/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Address2" /><BR/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Street" /><BR/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@City" /><BR/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Zip" />
</td>
</tr>
```

All five field will now be displayed in one field !